# How to move in the direction of the camera, OpenGL, c++

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm starting a 3D scene and I'm working on the movement of the "camera", or the entity moving around but I can't seem to get it to move in the direction it is facing.

[image: Example]

Does anyone have any guidance about how I'd begin to move in the direction of the camera? However I only want the entity to be moving along the x and z axis, as if it were on the floor and the y axis would be disregarded for now. If anyone could tell me what math is involved, it'd be really appreciated.

```
Camera::Camera(Vector3 * eye, Vector3 * center, Vector3 * up) {
    this->eye = eye;
    this->center = center;
    this->up = up;
}

Camera::Vector3 * getEye() { return eye; }
Camera::Vector3 * getCenter() { return center; }
Camera::Vector3 * getUp() { return up; }



camera = new Camera(new Vector3(5.0f, 3.0f, 5.0f), 
    new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 
    new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));


gluLookAt(camera->eye->getX(), camera->eye->getY(), camera->eye->getZ(),
            camera->center->getX(), camera->center->getY(), camera->center->getZ(),
            camera->up->getX(), camera->up->getY(), camera->up->getZ());//camera
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what is your eye, and center vector stand for. Could you post the line where are you using gluLookat() function?

Comment: You're right, I can't understand what is what either. We were given a snippet and were told to adapt. The line that calls the lookat function is above too. At the moment I'm manipulating these values to move the camera, along with translating the objects' position

Comment: okay so your camera position is eyeVector and your lookatPosition is centerVector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math behind is simple. You need 2 vec3 first (One for camera position and one for lookat position)

I assume your up vector is (0,1,0). So calculation should be like that :

```
vec3 lookatPosition;
vec3 cameraPosition;
vec3 upVector(0,1,0);
float movementSpeed;


vec3 forwardVector = lookatPosition - cameraPosition;

//You can generate like that if you don't have operator overload
//forwardVector.x = lookatPosition.x - cameraPosition.x;
//forwardVector.y = lookatPosition.y - cameraPosition.y;
//forwardVector.z = lookatPosition.z - cameraPosition.z;

forwardVector.normalise() // normalise your vector



//moving forward :
cameraPosition += forwardVector * movementSpeed;
lookatPosition += forwardVector * movementSpeed;

//Again you can do the operation like that if you don't have operator overloading
//cameraPosition.x += forwardVector.x * movementSpeed;
//cameraPosition.y += forwardVector.y * movementSpeed;
//cameraPosition.z += forwardVector.z * movementSpeed;

//moving backward :
cameraPosition -= forwardVector * movementSpeed;
lookatPosition -= forwardVector * movementSpeed;

//moving left :
vec3 leftVector = Crossproduct(upVector,forwardVector);
cameraPosition += leftVector * movementSpeed;
lookatPosition += leftVector * movementSpeed;


//moving right :
vec3 rightVector = Crossproduct(forwardVector,upVector);
cameraPosition += rightVector * movementSpeed;
lookatPosition += rightVector * movementSpeed;
```

**Note :** Data types and function names are not built in, you can implement your own datatype or use glm for vectors.

Comment: Hi thanks! I'll give this a shot. Would the first three Vector3s correspond with the 3 vectors in my original post? If you could re-check my original post that would be really helpful

Comment: Is there anything in particular I should need additionally for this line? camera->forwardVector = camera->position - camera->lookat;

as this is giving me an error. I didn't think I could subtract a vector3 from another vector3

Comment: if you asking for gluLookAt() function, your parameters are okay.

Comment: Yes. in my datatype I did operator overloading. You can subtract one by one

Comment: I mean when creating the "forwardVector", it's giving me the error that an int can't be assigned to a Vector3. Edit: Oh I see, i'll give that a shot thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can also extract your view vector directly from your view matrix - the one which you apply before rendering the scene itself.

The OpenGL model/view matrix looks like this:

```
|lx,ux,vx,px|     -- lx,ly,lz is your left-vector
|ly,uy,vy,py|     -- ux,uy,uz is your up-vector
|lz,uz,vz,pz|     -- vx,vy,vz is your view-vector
|0 ,0 ,0 ,1 |     -- px,py,pz is your translation
```

Simply extract your view vector by getting:

```
vx = matrix[2]; 
vy = matrix[6]; 
vz = matrix[10];
```

I usually do this after I've rotated my camera, in order to apply movement. It's a good practice to normalize these vectors before proceeding to do math with them.

Comment: you just saved me :D